# Como poder agregar un nuevo item dentro de una propiedad tipo array en un objeto?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6

Hola estoy tratando de utilizar la función for in para buscar el nombre de una propiedad tipo array que tengo dentro de un objeto y si existe guardar un item dentro de la propiedad. Pero el problema es que esta guardando el item en todos los array y lo que quiero  que solo guarde en el array que tenga como nombre la propiedad dada. Por ejemplo si tengo perros y gatos y llega un item desde gatos guarde el mismo dentro de gatos solamente.

----App.js

```
 class App extends Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        lists: [],
        items: {}
    };
}

handleAddItem(s) {
  let itemObj = s.ListName;
  let items = Object.assign({}, this.state.items);  
  for(itemObj in items){
    if(items.hasOwnProperty(itemObj)){
      items[itemObj].push(s);
    }
  }
  this.setState({ items  });
  }   
  render() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
    <AddList addList={this.handleAddList.bind(this)} />
    <div id="listsDiv" className="List">
      <Lists lists={this.state.lists} items={this.state.items} addItem=
   {this.handleAddItem.bind(this)} />
    </div>
  </div>
  );
  }

  }

  export default App;
```

-----Additem.js

```
/* global location */
  /* eslint no-restricted-globals: ["off", "location"] */

  import React, { Component } from 'react';

 class AddItem extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  newItem:{}
  }
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the page from reloading -- do not 
 delete this line!
 let newItem = Object.assign({}, this.state.newItem); 
 newItem.name = this.refs.id.value;
 newItem.listName = this.props.idName;
 this.setState({ newItem: this.state.newItem = newItem });

 this.props.addItem(this.state.newItem);
  console.log(this.state.newItem);

 }


 render() {
 var divName = 'add' + this.props.idName;
 return (
  <div className='addItemDiv'>
  <h4>Add {this.props.idName}</h4>
  <form ref='form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
  <div id={divName} ref={divName}>
    <label>Name</label><br />
    <input type='text' ref='id' />
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    <br />
  </form>
  </div>
   );
 }

 }

 export default AddItem;
```

---Lists

```
class Lists extends Component {

render() {
// If there are no lists, display a relevant message
if(this.props.lists.length === 0) {
  return (
    <div id="listsDiv" className="List">
      <h2>Add new lists to get started!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
// Otherwise, for each list, create a div
var items = this.props.items; 
var lists = this.props.lists;
var addItem = this.props.addItem;
console.log(items);
return (

  <div key={uuidv4()}>
  {
    lists.map(function(listName){
    return (
      <List name={listName} items={items[listName]} addItem=
 {addItem.bind(this)} key={uuidv4()} />
    )
  })
  }
  </div>
  );
  }
 }

 export default Lists;
```

Comment: Creo que tu código no esta completo, por favor revisa que sea un [mcve]

Comment: Hola Ruslan ya le agregue otras partes que creo que seran neccesarias para hacer los test. Realmente el problema que tengo ahora es que no se como filtrar el objeto en App.js donde quiero guardar el item que viene de AddItem.js, me sigue guardando en cuanto objetos tengo y eso no es lo que quiero.

Comment: agregue la estructura de como tiene creado el 'items' que usa en el 'for'

Comment: Esta la estructura en el state del App.js . El items es un objeto que guarda propiedades tipo array. ejemplo items{ Gato: [], Perro: [], ....}. En lo que deseo me ayuden es a ir guardando segun el nombre de la propiedad los items en cada array dentro del objeto items

Answer (score 1):

Debes poner una condición para ello.

```
for (itemObj in items) {
    if (itemObj === nameObj) { // Si coincide 
        items[itemObj].push(nameObj); // lo añades
        console.log(itemObj + " = " + items[itemObj], items);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adolfo gracias por responder pero no es la idea. Lo que quiero es buscar primero la propiedad del objeto por el key y si coincide con el que estoy pasando entonces guardar el item en el array

Comment: Hola alguien puede ayudarme con este tema? he provado varias variantes pero aun me sigue sin filtrar el property en el objeto.

Comment: No entiendo bien qué es lo que quieres en realidad, para buscar la propiedad recorres el array con el bucle `FOR` por todos los "items" y en ese proceso cazas el item deseado comparándolo con el  `IF`, en ese momento es cuando puedes actualizar ese mismo ítem.